# Read "myfile.xml" from all localizations

Tags: java, android, xml, file, localization

I have some data contained in different `myfile.xml` files for each localization of my android app, in :

- values/ myfile.xml
- values-de/ myfile.xml
- values-en/ myfile.xml
- values-en-rGB/ myfile.xml
- ...

Is there a simple way to retrieve some data from all of those localized file ? (Instead of read all files , check if it's the right file and parse it with an XML Reader and retrieve values for all localization. I haven't test even if it's possible).

**Edit**, example :
values/ myfile.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="url">http://example.com/</string>
</resources>
```

values-de/ myfile.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="url">http://example.net/</string>
</resources>
```

values-en/ myfile.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="url">http://example.org/</string>
</resources>
```

...

From those file, I want to retrieve the list of all url, whatever the locale the app is running on.

**Second Edit:**

Example of what I've tried, not a good method :

```
List<String> urls;

public void init(Context c){
    Locale lBase = Locale.getDefault();

    // Iter all languages availables
    for(Lang l : LanguageSpinner.langs){

        // set the locale
        Locale locale = new Locale(l.getlCode());
        updateLocale(c, locale);

        // Retrieve data and push to the list
        String url = c.getString(R.string.url);
        urls.add(url);
    }

    // re-set the default locale
    updateLocale(c, lBase);
}


public static void updateLocale(Context context, Locale l){
    Locale.setDefault(l);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = l;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: You can do it with `Strings.xml` inside each folder

Comment: I already have a file in each folder, I want to read all of them and don't care about which locale the app is running on.

Comment: myfile.xml will automatically read according to location

Comment: So i need to extract all the data i want and put it in an other shared xml file ? No way to accomplish what i want ?

Comment: `values` folder is not a good place to keep the files then. Try with `assets` folder.

Comment: those values are used with the string.xml "engine" in some parts of the app, cannot move them.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to **parse an XML file**, it doesn't work like that!

But **this** method works for me (I use it to display a localized html file in a WebView fragment, which is used to provide a "User Guide"):

Put all your files in your `/assets` folder (eventually under some other folder, like `/assets/data`).
Name each file something like `myfile-en.xml`, `myfile-de.xml`, ...

```
    String strLang = "fr"; // or "en", "de", "es", "it", ...
    String strFile = String.format
    (
        "file:///android_asset/data/myfile-%s.xml", strLang
    );
```

strFile will contain the path to your localized file.

You can automatically set `strLang` taking it from your current locale, like this:

```
String strLang = Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language().substring(0, 2);
```

---

If you only want to retrieve a localized string, just use the syntax:

```
String myString = getResources().getString(R.string.url);
```

Comment: I cant actually choose your method, the files are already there and contain lot of values and are used with the string.xml "engine"

Comment: So what? what does it take you to move the files from one folder to another one?

Comment: I didn't ask for a structure modification, just "is it possible to ?". I have 18 localizations and i can't and don't want to change the file structure, I just want to get 1 value of each localized xml file. (I know how use "assets" or other techniques to do that), sorry.

Comment: Well, so **you don't need what you asked**. You asked for PARSING XML FILES (`and parse it with an XML Reader`). While you just need to use the `String myString = getResources().getString(R.string.url);` syntax. NO XML PARSING.

Comment: Is there a simple way to retrieve some data from all of those localized file ? that was my question.. I just wanted to know the easiest way (and if it was possible) to retrieve datas from whatever string.xml file contained in whatever values-locale.
Ex : my app start with english locale and i want to retrieve all "url" fields contained in those files

Comment: Since you are using the strings.xml mechanism (which is independent from the file name - it uses the values-xy name), you use this `String myString = getResources().getString(R.string.url);` **but only for your current locale**.

Comment: So what you're answering me is that hacking the locale 18 times to retrieve a list containing all those values is the only way to keep my file structure ?

Comment: You can see my answer for the solution i didn't want to choose.

Comment: It was the one I myself wanted to suggest you. then I saw you gave a similar one: `Force the locale, get the string. Iterate`.